# PHP redirect but keep page in history

Tags: php, redirect

Every page on my site does a login check. If the user is not logged in, they are redirected to the login page.  But after they log in, if they want to go to that page they were redirected from it is missing from the browser history.  So...

1. I'm on Page A
2. I click to Page B. Oops!  My session timed out and I'm not logged in.
3. I'm redirected to Login Page (using PHP `header( 'Location:http://example.com/login.php');` function).  I log in.
4. If I hit "Back", I go to Page A.  Page B is NOT in history.

How can I make it so hitting the Back button takes me to Page B?

EDIT for clarification: Back takes me to login page again. Back a second time takes me to Page A.

Comment: you should do something like `header( 'Location:http://example.com/login.php?ref=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` you will then do a  `header( 'Location:'. $_GET['ref']);` when the user logs in to redirect them to the correct page

Comment: Making use of `REQUEST_URI` or `HTTP_REFERER` to intelligently redirect the user to their desired page after authentication is probably your best approach.  Anything else requires implementation of JavaScript and messing with the History API with mixed results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the login page redirect the user to the page which they were previously browsing. Basically, during your authentication function, you would grab the current URL or query string and save it for after a successful login.

There are a few different methods of storing this, either

- Cookies (see documentation for `setcookie()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php))
- Session (see documentation for `$_SESSION` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php))
- In the URL, by encoding the previous URL as a variable and passing so you would redirect to `http://example.com/login.php?redirect=somepage.php`

Once the login is successful, you would load that page rather than the general home page.

However, this doesn't specifically address the question you asked. In terms of altering the browser history, as was mentioned in the comments, you would need to use Javascript, and the History API documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Comment: Wouldn't that lose the POST and GET info from when they were previously there?

Comment: It would, but if you were saving the destination URL, you could also save the `$_REQUEST` data and restore it, though this could be dangerous. Part of that depends on the page itself and how dynamic it is and how much it relies on `$_POST` and `$_GET` content. However (personally), when a session is expired, I would prefer to have a full reset of the `$_REQUEST` array anyway, since the state has changed.